# switching between $\Bbb P_3[\Bbb R]$ and $\Bbb R^4$ vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

first of all I couldn't find a better way of describing what I really meant so here it goes.
Lets say I have a vector space $\mathbb{P}_3[\mathbb{R}]$
and a sub vector space $U = \textrm{span}\{ x^2 + 1, x+8, 8x \}$.

I am trying to figure out if $U$ can also be presented by:
sub vector space of $\mathbb{R}^4$, so in this case:
$W = \textrm{span}\{(1,0,1,0),(8,1,0,0),(0,8,0,0)\}$.

If so, could I also count on doing so for matrices as well?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes.  Essentially, $P_3$ (*the set of polynomials of degree 3 or less*) and $\Bbb R^4$ both are four dimensional vector spaces over the same field.  Finite dimensional vector spaces of the same dimension over the same field are indeed isomorphic and so there exist change of bases from one to the other.  Note that the vector space of $2\times 2$ matrices is also isomorphic to $\Bbb R^4$.  Instead of $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ you can work with $(a,b,c,d)$.

Comment: What changes is the flavor and natural problems to ask, such as differentiation for $P_3$ is natural to talk about but isn't as natural to talk about in $\Bbb R^4$ (though it can be done).  Or, the set of matrices such that they commute with a specific matrix using multiplication.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for the reply. So then when it comes to finding a basis for P3; it is good enough to present the vectors in as in R4 and by elimination process over a suitable matrice and I find the linearily independent vectors and then switch back to P3 presentaion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, no. $\mathbb{P}_3$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$ are not literally the same space, so your $U$ and $W$ are again not literally the same space. However, $\mathbb{P}_3$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$ are 4 dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$. All vector spaces over a fixed field with a fixed finite dimension are isomorphic. One can construct an isomorphism by choosing a basis for each space, matching up the basis elements, then extending linearly. So for instance you have the isomorphism defined by $1 \mapsto e_1,x \mapsto e_2,x^2 \mapsto e_3,x^3 \mapsto e_4$. Your $U$ is isomorphic to your $W$ under this isomorphism. So roughly speaking, any linear algebra you might want to do in $\mathbb{P}_3$ can be done in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and then transported back by the isomorphism.